# Shiny reactiveUI reseting value on reload

Tags: r, shiny

One can use reactiveUI interfaces in shiny to selectively show inputs variables that are relevant only at certain times. Here is an example with a variable "a", which depending on the value causes the interface to show variables "c" or "d":

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("a","choose selection",list("c","d")),
        uiOutput("b")),
      mainPanel(verbatimTextOutput("text"))
    )))
```

server.R

```
choice_list <- list(
  "c" = selectInput("c", "first set of choices", choices = list("cat","dog","house")),
  "d" = selectInput("d", "second set of choices", choices = list("money","power","fame")))
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$b <- renderUI({
    choice_list[input$a]
  })  
  output$text <- renderText(paste0(input$c,input$d))
})
```

So this works good and well, as you can see depending on the context you can select different items. My issue is that each time you switch `a` the value of what you switch to (either `c` or `d`) resets to its default. That isn't a problem here with only one input being shown at a time, but if you imagine that many different input parameters are being shown at once having them all reset each time you switch them in would be awful. Is there any way to store the previous values so that when shiny reloads the UI they don't reset?

Just for a bit more detail, this is just an example of what I am doing with a much larger set of code. I have different analyses the user could run, and each have their own lists of input objects. However they also have a large overlap --many of the input objects in one list show up in another. Currently each time you switch between which analysis you want to do, the entire set of inputs resets, which is very annoying for the users.

Each analysis has some code that it uses to run, and also a list of UI objects to use. These objects live in a different file, which is similar to how the `choice_list` lives outside of the `shinyServer` function.

Comment: You can wrap this around a dependency once it has been executed i.e. if you have a reactive expression and the button that the user presses. Upon execution write these selections and store them as global variables using <<- assignment, then when a user whats to go back to the previous tabPanel if you have one it will remember the inputs.

Comment: How do global variables work with multiple people using shiny? Does each instance have its own set of global variables, or if two people are connected to it at once will they be changing the same variables?

Comment: Global variables will be shared along every session (meaning e very person that logs in). If you change it then the 'memorised' variables should be visible to everyone. Anything you type into the server function will be visible only to the individual users (sessions) that connect to the app, which you can have 'unlimited'.
for more info on above go here http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#scoping

To quick fix this I can think of one thing at the moment: You can force another instance of an app through a different port then you will have 2 apps running on your machine at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way. Here I store the current selections as global variables and the `selectInput` calls as expressions, which I evaluate afresh each time `input$a` changes.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("a","choose selection",list("c","d")),
        uiOutput("b")),
      mainPanel(verbatimTextOutput("text"))
    ))

c.selected <- 'cat'
d.selected <- 'money'

choice_list <- list(
  "c" = quote(selectInput("c", "first set of choices", choices = list("cat","dog","house"), selected=c.selected)),
  "d" = quote(selectInput("d", "second set of choices", choices = list("money","power","fame"), selected=d.selected))
  )

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$b <- renderUI({
    eval(choice_list[[input$a]])
  })  

  observe({
    c.selected <<- input$c
  })

  observe({
    d.selected <<- input$d
  })


  output$text <- renderText(paste0(input$c,input$d))
}

runApp(list(ui=ui, server=server))
```